# How to register a class to IoC in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, prism, dryioc

I write an application with WPF. I use the Prism library with IoC as Prism.DryIoC.
I have an AppDbContext.cs class to declare the connection string to the database (here is MongoDB)

```
public class AppDbContext : BaseMongoRepository
{
    public AppDbContext(string connectionString, string databaseName = null) : base(connectionString, databaseName)
    {
    }
}
```

I have a class MyService.cs that uses the AppDbContext class, I declare in the constructor.
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private AppDbContext _dbContext;

```
    public IdentifierRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer model)
    {
        // Some code....
        _dbContext.Add(model);
    }
}
```

In the App.xaml.cs class I override the method

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();


    // MongoDB
    var connectionString = SharedCommon.LocalAppSettings.Database.ConnectionString;
    var database         = SharedCommon.LocalAppSettings.Database.DatabaseName;

    // How to register class MyService.cs here?
    // I dont known.
    containerRegistry<MyService>(() => new MyService(new AppDbContext(connectionString, database))); // Wrong code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the registration methods [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Ioc/IContainerRegistryExtensions.cs).

For **singleton** `MyService`:

```
var myService = new MyService(new AppDbContext(connectionString, database)));
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(myService);
```

For **multiple instances** you could use a factory instead.

```
public class MyServiceFactory
{
    private readonly AppDbContext appDbContext;
    public MyServiceFactory(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        this.appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public MyService Create() => new MyService(appDbContext);
}
```

Register the instance of the *factory*:

```
var context = new AppDbContext(connectionString, database);
var factory = new MyServiceFactory(context);

containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(factory);
```

Then create your service instance:

```
var factory = container.Resolve<MyServiceFactory>();
var service = factory.Create();
```

Comment: This will register a singleton service, while the (pseudo-)code in the question registers a transient service.

Comment: Yes! It worked as expected. And how to register as Transient service?

Comment: See update. (There might be a simpler way to get a factory pattern in `DryIoc`.)

Comment: This answer is very complete, helping me understand the nature of IoC. One more time thank you very much